# Dynamic formula adjustment after loading new data file through VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba, excel-formula, formula

Could someone please help me with the below, which I have been struggling with for a few days. Maybe there's an entirely better way to do it, which I haven't thought of?

Every day I have to load an XML file into an existing Excel spreadsheet. The XML schema is always the same, but the number of rows could vary dramatically. Most days it is within 250-300 rows, but sometimes could be as low as 50 and as high as 2,000.

In the existing Excel spreadsheet there are then some formulas which need to take data from the cells in the loaded XML table  -those are columns A and B. The XML table is then columns C to F.

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Direction | Overdue | Customer Name | Customer Surname | Payment Balance | Due Date |
| =IF(E2>0, "We owe", "They owe") | =IF(F2>today(), "No", "Yes" | John | Doe | -100 | 01/07/2021 |

Because the number of rows keeps changing and to avoid any issues, before I load a new file, I clear contents using the below code. However, the formulas in columns A and B then automatically start referencing the rows, after which I have cleared the contents. For example, you can see the formulas reference cells E2 and F2. Let's say yesterday's XML table had 30 rows, when I run my clear contents code, the formulas in A2 and B2 start referencing E31 and F31 all of a sudden. Any idea how I can stop this?

```
    Worksheets("My data").Activate
    Range("H:AO").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could build in replication of the formula from the first cell desired (assuming "A2", per your table) then drag this down the desired number of cells.  For instance, if it's always the case that you clear C:F (from 2nd row down, as opposed to some other cells H:AO, which technically fall outside the scope of the sample data you provided! ☺), then A2 could be reproduced / replicated from '*ground-up*' as follows:

```
Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[4]>0, ""We owe"", ""They owe"")"
x = Range("c:c").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count - 2
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2", Range("A2").Offset(x))
Calculate
```

**Application**

Screenshot below refers - if we assume this is the new xml scheme (reflected within excel, C2:G5, then above code determines number of rows (based upon FName col, C) to apply following function (per your Q):

```
=IF(E2>0, "We owe", "They owe")
```

This starts from A2 and is applied across 4 cells (A2:A5) to align with last cell in col C.

**Limitations**

This is based upon cell count (equivalent to excel function 'counta') - nothing is said re: blank/missing first names - so cognisance of this should be factored into account (could reduce following VB code by presence of null values as req.):

```
x = Range("c:c").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count - 2
```

Courtesy, DonkeyOte, [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/use-vba-to-count-non-blank-cells-in-a-column.32797/).

[image: Sample data - illustrating application of VB code herewith]

*Reproducing other function-driven cells (*viz*. col B, relevant range) can follow suit.*